# Dataframe - R - Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

i have a question regarding Shiny and the usage of Data frames.

I think i understood that i need to create isolated or reactive environmentes to interact with, but if i try to work with the Dataframe i get an error message:

```
Error in pfData: konnte Funktion "pfData" nicht finden
```

i tried to manipulate the dataframe by this code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
observeEvent(input$go,
           {
             pf_name <- reactive({input$pfID})
             pf_date <- reactive({input$pfDate})

             if (pf_name()!="please select a PF") {
               
               pfData <- reactive(read.csv(file =paste(pf_name(),".csv",sep=""),sep=";",dec=","))
               MDur <- pfData()[1,15]
               pfData <- pfData()[3:nrow(pfData()),]
               Total = sum(pfData()$Eco.Exp...Value.long)

               }
           })
}
```

If i manipulate my Dataframe in the console it works just fine:

```
pfData <- pfData[3:nrow(pfData),]
Total = sum(pfData$Eco.Exp...Value.long)
Assets = sum(as.numeric(gsub(",",".",gsub(".","",pfData$Value,fixed=TRUE),fixed=TRUE)))
pfData$Exposure <- with(pfData, Eco.Exp...Value.long /Total)
```

can you help  me?

Edit:

```
 library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  
fluidRow(
  
        column(6, offset =3,
               wellPanel(
                 "Choose Mandate and Date",
                         fluidRow(
                           column(4,selectInput("pfID",label = "",
                                                       choices = list("please select a PF","GF25", 
                                                                      "FPM"),
                                                       selected = "please select a PF") ), 
                                  column(4,   dateInput("pfDate",label="",value = Sys.Date())  ),
                           column(2,  actionButton("go","Submit")),column(2,textOutput("selected_var"))
                           )
                        )
              )
      )

)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  pfDataReactive <- reactive({
    input$go
    if (pf_name()!="please select a PF") {
      pfData <- read.csv(file =paste(pf_name(),".csv",sep=""),sep=";",dec=",")
      MDur <- pfData[1,15]
      pfData <- pfData[3:nrow(pfData),]
      Total = sum(pfData$Eco.Exp...Value.long)
      Assets = sum(as.numeric(gsub(",",".",gsub(".","",pfData$Value,fixed=TRUE),fixed=TRUE)))
      pfData$Exposure <- with(pfData, Eco.Exp...Value.long /Total)
      pfData
      output$selected_var <- renderText({paste(MDur)})
      }
  })
  
  

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a `reactive` rather than using `observeEvent`.

Try something like

```
pfDataReactive <- reactive({
  input$go
  pfData <- read.csv(file =paste(pf_name(),".csv",sep=""),sep=";",dec=",")
  Total = sum(pfData$Eco.Exp...Value.long)
  Assets = sum(as.numeric(gsub(",",".",gsub(".","",pfData$Value,fixed=TRUE),fixed=TRUE)))
  pfData$Exposure <- with(pfData, Eco.Exp...Value.long /Total)
  pfData
})
```

And then use `pfDataReactive()` in your Shiny app's server function wherever you would refer to `pfData` in your console code.

The standalone reference to `input$go` ensures the reactive will update whenever `input$go` changes/is clicked/etc.

### Update

There are still significant issues with your code.  You've added an assignment to an output object as the last line of the `reactive` I gave you, so the `reactive` always returns `NULL`.  That's not helpful and is one of the reasons why it "doesn't active at all"...

Second, you test for the existence of an reactive/function called `pf_name` when the relevant input object appears to be `input$pfID`.  That's another reason why the `reactive` is never updated.

Note the change to the definition of `input$pfID` that I've made to improve the readability of the `pfDataReactive` object.  (This change also probably means that you can do away with `input$go` entirely.)

As you say, I don't have access to your csv file, so I can't test your code completely.   I've modified the body of the `pfDataReactive` to simply return the `mtcars` dataset as a string.  I've also edited the code I've commented out to hopefully run correctly when you use it with the *real* csv file.

This code appears to give the behaviour you want,.  Though, if I may make a subjective comment, I think the layout of your GUI is appaling. ;=)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, offset =3,
           wellPanel(
             "Choose Mandate and Date",
             fluidRow(
               column(4,selectInput("pfID",label = "",
                                    # Modified to that "Pleaseselect a PF" returns NULL
                                    choices = list("please select a PF"="","GF25",  "FPM"),
                                    selected = "please select a PF") ), 
               column(4,   dateInput("pfDate",label="",value = Sys.Date())  ),
               column(2,  actionButton("go","Submit")),column(2,textOutput("selected_var"))
             )
           )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  pfDataReactive <- reactive({
    # Don't do anything until we have a PF csv file
    req(input$pfID)
    
    input$go
    # Note the change to the creation of the file name
      # pfData <- read.csv(file =paste(input$pfID,".csv",sep=""),sep=";",dec=",")
      # pfData <- pfData[3:nrow(pfData),]
      # Total = sum(pfData$Eco.Exp...Value.long)
      # Assets = sum(as.numeric(gsub(",",".",gsub(".","",pfData$Value,fixed=TRUE),fixed=TRUE)))
      # pfData$Exposure <- with(pfData, Eco.Exp...Value.long /Total)
      # MDur <- pfData[1,15]
      # If you want to print MDur in the selected_var output, MDur should be the retrun value from this reactive
      # MDur
      mtcars
  })
  
  output$selected_var <- renderText({
    print("Yep!")
    as.character(pfDataReactive())
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[This](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) is a good introduction to Shiny.

Comment: Hi Limey, thank you for your help. tried your way but seems like it doesnt active at all. 

Since you miss the csv it is hard to have a working example but this would be my complete code. See the edited text above!